# How can I change it so checkboxes instead of text appear?

Tags: javascript, java, android, search, checkbox

How can I change it so checkboxes instead of text appear ?
Now the user can search for Canada and the app shows the user the text canada.
Now I want to but that instead the text I can find checkboxes.

How does this work?

Thank you very much!

Best Regards,
Fabian

.java

```html
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] items;
    ArrayList<String> listItems;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView listView;
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtsearch);
        initList();
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(s.toString().equals("")){
                    // reset listview (resette listview)
                    initList();
                }
                else{
                    // perform search
                    searchItem(s.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

    }


    public void searchItem(String textToSearch){
        for(String item:items){
            if(!item.contains(textToSearch)) {
                listItems.remove(item);
            }

        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public void initList(){
        items=new String[]{"Canada","China"};
        listItems=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, R.id.txtitem, listItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

.xml

```html
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Text"
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Buttontext"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />



    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtsearch"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:hint="search"
        />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you'd like the application to look like, but in order to create a list of checkboxes, you can simply have a vertically oriented LinearLayout that contains these checkboxes.

The implementation depends on whether your data source is static or dynamic.

**Static:**
If you wish to create a static list of checkboxes, you can simply add them to a LinearLayout (like shown below), and then add this LinearLayout to your main layout (instead of the ListView):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layout_cbx" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbx_canada"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Canada" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbx_china"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="China"
        android:checked="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Dynamic:**
If you wish to create the checkboxes dynamically (which is the common case), first create a LinearLayout to be a container:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layout_cbx" />
```

And then add the checkboxes in your activity (for example, add the following to onCreate after initList):

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_cbx);
        for(String item : items){
            CheckBox cbx = new CheckBox(this);
            cbx.setText(item);
            layout.addView(cbx);
        }
```

**Edit:**
As you used the static resource, your searchItem method should include something like that for each checkbox:

```
CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbx_china);
cbx.setChecked(textToSearch == cbx.getText());
cbx = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbx_canada);
cbx.setChecked(textToSearch == cbx.getText());
```

Again, this is not the best practice in my opinion.

Comment: Whats the difference of dynamic and not dynamic check boxes?

Comment: Dynamic loading means that you load the data in runtime after it was received from a source (local/remote database, a web interface, etc.). Static means that the checkboxes does not depend on external resources and can be manually written. Anyway, you can dynamically load it also from a hardcoded list, which I think would be better than manually code it in the layout.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. Please look to my new post.

Comment: Where? I couldn't find it. Please give me a link.

Comment: I make this post as a answer.

Comment: You don't need two xmls. layout_cbx should be inside your home xml, instead of the ListView, so you'll only have one xml, and of course change it in setContentView.

Comment: I need this ListView?, because than the style ist very bad.

Comment: <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtsearch"
        android:hint="Zutaten suchen"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtsearch"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></ListView>´

Comment: You don't need a ListView. You need one layout that contains an EditText and a LinearLayout with checkboxes.

Comment: Thank you very very much!! Now the layout looks perfect, but the search function doesnt work.

Comment: It's probably because you didn't change your searchItem method. You should reimplement it based on how you want it to react (check the matching checkbox or remove unmatched checkboxes).

Comment: Please look to my new answer. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Note that in searchItem you refer to a ArrayList that is irrelevant (because you hardcoded the checkboxes). Instead of that, you should check if the string matches each checkbox's text and make it checked if it does.

Comment: I added it to my main answer. Once you manage to make it all work, I suggest you to try the dynamic loading, which is the best practice in my opinion.

Comment: Please look to my new answer. Thank you very very much!

Comment: I edited my answer again. You need to put the snippet I supplied in your searchItem method, instead of its current implementation.

Comment: Than I will use the Dynamic method.I need than two or one xml layout files?

Comment: Anyway you need only one. The only xml difference is that you should remove the hardcoded checkboxes. Instead, you add them as explained above.

Comment: I think the Static method is better, because thats clear.

Comment: In the static method the "textToSearch" is in the color red? Whats happened?

Comment: I'm not sure what changes you have made. Anyway, if you have further questions I can help you in email, neria.nachum at gmail.com, but I strongly recommend you to read a bit in the android documentation first: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html.

Answer (score 0):

```
    you should add or change <CheckBox> according to your requirement for the output 
    like

    <!----Your java class---->
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    <!----Your java class---->
     public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

             final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);
             if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                 checkBox.setChecked(false);
//Rest of your code
             }
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

What should I change exactly ? 
Please fill this in the code and delete the not used code:

```js
CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbx_china);
if (textToSearch == cbx.getText())
cbx.setChecked(!cbx.isChecked());
```

I´m so sorry, but I´m confused at the moment.

```js
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] items;
    ArrayList<String> listItems;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView listView;
    EditText editText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
// CheckBox
        final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbx_canada);
        if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
            checkBox.setChecked(false);
            

            //listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtsearch);
            initList();
            editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    if (s.toString().equals("")) {
                        // reset listview (resette listview)
                        initList();
                    } else {
                        // perform search
                        searchItem(s.toString());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });

        }}


    public void searchItem(String textToSearch){
        for(String item:items){
            if(!item.contains(textToSearch)) {
                listItems.remove(item);
            }

        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public void initList(){
        items=new String[]{"Canada","China"};//////////////////////////////////////
        listItems=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_home, R.id.activity_home, listItems); // List item dazugefügt
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    // Menüs //

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!
Best Regards,
Fabian